# Add default table Discriminator field to entities - Discriminator field is null

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a Table Per Hierarchy architecture, and so I have the Discriminator field added to my tables by default which is a varchar. I'm trying to add this field to my entities and send it back to the client in the http response.

I've added it to my base entities:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class DomainEntity<TId> : IDomainEntity<TId>
{
    [Key]
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}
```

And in the dataContext:

```
// Vegan Item (this is an abstract class with several concrete subclasses)

modelBuilder.Entity<VeganItem>(veganItem =>
{
    veganItem.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
    veganItem.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
    veganItem.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    veganItem.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    veganItem.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    veganItem.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    veganItem.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Tags)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, null),
            new ValueComparer<IList<Option>>(
                (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => (IList<Option>)c.ToList()));
});

// Vegan Item Establishments (these are concrete classes, I just had to do it that way to get the generics right.)

modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemEstablishment>(giEstablishment => 
{
    giEstablishment.HasIndex(g => new { g.VeganItemId, g.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
    giEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
    giEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    giEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    giEstablishment.HasOne(g => g.VeganItem)
        .WithMany(vi => vi.VeganItemEstablishments)
        .HasForeignKey(g => g.VeganItemId);
    giEstablishment.HasOne(g => g.Establishment)
        .WithMany(e => e.VeganItemEstablishments)
        .HasForeignKey(g => g.EstablishmentId);
    giEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    giEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemEstablishment>(miEstablishment => 
{
    miEstablishment.HasIndex(m => new { m.VeganItemId, m.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
    miEstablishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    miEstablishment.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
    miEstablishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    miEstablishment.HasOne(m => m.VeganItem)
        .WithMany(vi => vi.VeganItemEstablishments)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.VeganItemId);
    miEstablishment.HasOne(m => m.Establishment)
        .WithMany(e => e.VeganItemEstablishments)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.EstablishmentId);
    miEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    miEstablishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
});
```

But when I receive a POST Request with a `GroceryItemEstablishment` in the data, the `GroceryItemEstablishment` has a null `Discriminator` field but its `veganItem` which is a field on it, has a populated `Discriminator` field. Any ideas why one of them is null?

[image]
[image]

It is populated in the db:

[image]

Comment: Does it appear by chance? If not, is it possible that missed configuration in some place?

Comment: @TinyWang When it arrives from the client side, it seems to populate the Discriminator in my back end controllers even when the client didn't send it, for the `GroceryItem` but not the `GroceryItemEstablishment`. So it must be some EF Core magic, that works automatically due to the configuration of those entities. So yeah, i guess my `GroceryItemEstablishment` is configured wrong somehow. I ended up just sending it from the client side in the end as a workaround, however it would still be good to know why one class worked and one didn't.